# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Repeatingly increase an object size with certain amount of px](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26615/repeatingly-increase-an-object-size-with-certain-amount-of-px)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the name for the long dashes that sometimes replace the inner letters of a name?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26566/what-is-the-name-for-the-long-dashes-that-sometimes-replace-the-inner-letters-of)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I change the color of this object properly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-this-object-properly)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does a graphic designer run the risk of losing clients if he/she publishes instructional books and tutorials for non-designers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26730/does-a-graphic-designer-run-the-risk-of-losing-clients-if-he-she-publishes-instr)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How to center text vertically within a textbox in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/how-to-center-text-vertically-within-a-textbox-in-photoshop)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Is there a recommended neutral color palette for web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26479/is-there-a-recommended-neutral-color-palette-for-web-design)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why does Chrome distort my transparent PNG (adding a subtle inset "weak" area)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26243/why-does-chrome-distort-my-transparent-png-adding-a-subtle-inset-weak-area)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I find font references in a Photoshop PSD file?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26560/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-there-are-any-font-references-in-a-photoshop-psd-file)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to convert pen-shape path to a working path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25920/how-to-convert-shape-borders-to-paths)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Photo distorts terribly on Facebook](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26358/photo-distorts-terribly-on-facebook)

**Net Score: -10** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 10)

---